# variable $data doesn't seem to pass through to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having issues figuring out why my $data variable isn't passing to my search_view, I pass sql data from model as shown below:

```
        $this->db->like('LOWER(title)', strtolower($query));
        $q = $this->db->get('questions');
        $data = $q->row_array();
        $q->free_result();

        $this->load->view('search_view', $data);
```

and than try to echp out a row in my search_view for example `echo $data['title'];` however get an error saying that variable data is undefined.

I tested it and echoed same thing out without loading a view, just an echo from model works. So I am sure it is getting correct data from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $this->load->view('search_view', array('data'=>$data));
```

and in view file

```
 echo $data['title'];
```

Comment: you are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the array you pass become variables in the view, It's

```
echo $title;
```

instead of

```
echo $data['title'];
```

Comment: Have tried it, still get an error saying title is undefined variable :/

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `$data` contains a `title` element on the first level?

Comment: Yes, I tried echoing it out without loading a view and got expected result.